# Check if UTC time is within range

Tags: utc

I've looked over several threads and none seem to work for my issue.  I would like to check if the current UTC time is within 4 specified UTC ranges.  When I return the current UTC time I get epoch time and I'm having trouble doing the comparison when entering the UTC time as a string, i.e. "2100".

Here's what I used to return the current UTC time:

```
   nd = new Date();
   Date.prototype.getUTCTime = function () {
        return this.getTime() - (this.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
    };

    var utcTime = nd.getUTCTime();
    alert("the current utc time is" + utcTime);
```

Also tried to concatenate

```
  // get time for UTC clock

    zhour = nd.getUTCHours();
    zmin = nd.getUTCMinutes();


    if (zhour < 10) { zhour = "0" + zhour }
    if (zmin <= 9) { zmin = "0" + zmin }

    hourPlusMin = zhour + "" + zmin;
    utcTime = Number(hourPlusMin);
```

I need to check if utcTime is within one of these ranges:

2100-0300,
0300-0900,
0900-1500,
1500-2100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be easiest if you think in terms of "minutes since midnight UTC."  e.g.:

```
function isInRange(nd, start, end) {
    // convert nd to minutes from midnight
    var minsFromMidnight = nd.getUTCHours() * 60 + nd.getUTCMinutes();

    // convert start and end times (e.g. "0351" and "2115") to minutes from midnight;
    var startMins = (Math.floor(parseInt(start) / 100) * 60) + (parseInt(start) % 60);
    var endMins = (Math.floor(parseInt(end) / 100) * 60) + (parseInt(end) % 60);

    // return whether or not our nd is within the range
    // account for time ranges the cross the day boundary by checking
    // (e.g. end time is less than start time)
    if (endMins > startMins)
        return (minsFromMidnight >= startMins && minsFromMidnight <= endMins);
    else
        return (minsFromMidnight >= startMins || minsFromMidnight <= endMins);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this works.  2100 is technically also 3hrs or 180min from midnight.  If the start time is 2100 and end time is 0300 for the range, and the current UTC time is within the range it fails.

Comment: Ahh - yes, crossing over the midnight boundary.  I edited my answer to check for that condition upon returning.  See above -

Comment: It did!  Thanks for your help.